# Determine whether string contained within another string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking to determine whether a string is fully contained at the start of a list of other string. For example if i had the string `cde`, and the list of strings:

```
  ['ab', 'bce', 'cdef']
```

then it would be determine that `cde` is contained at the start of `cdef`

I'm also looking to go the other way around - i.e. if i had the term `abc` to identify that `ab` from the above list is contained within it.

Now obviously this is trivial to set up with a for loop, checking each instance with the function `startswith`, however this is not scalable with a very large list of possibilities to check on.

While checking each instance is O(n) [and hence very slow if you have 100,000 possibilities], i am looking for a way of checking of O(1)  ... it feels like if the "list" was pre-sorted, then can simply extract the nearest match, but not sure how.

Clarification:

- I solely looking where there is a perfect match at the start of the string (i.e the whole of search term is included).
- I will be looking up multiple search terms (thus while initially sorting the data may not be quick, the sunk cost would save on subsequent look troughs).
- Ideally would return every possible match (i.e. if `cdef` and `cdefg` where in the list, and looking up `cde`, then both would be returned).
- I use the term "list" loosely, as in a collection of terms.

Comment: Please clarify the problem.  Are all the needed strings included within the list?  Do you need just one match, or all matches?  Are the matches only at the start of the string?

Comment: Note that sorting the list is no better than O(n log n), so your O(n) idea is not going to happen.  Also, note that string checking is at least O(m), on the length of the shorter string.  Please make sure that you are clear when you talk about the complexity: whether it's a step or the entire pass.

Comment: You can get to O(n) over the course of many string checks. I'm working on something

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in *O(1)*, since by definition you have to go over the entire array. If the array is sorted then you can do a binary search for your string, and then check if the element at that position starts with your string. That operation is *O(log n)*.

```
import bisect

# return the index of the string starting with the prefix
# or None if no such string is in the list
def search(a, prefix):
    i = bisect.bisect_left(a, prefix)
    isAtStart = (i < len(a) and a[i].startswith(prefix))
    return i if isAtStart else None

search(['ab', 'bce', 'cdef'], 'bc')
```